# Proof of Mermin-Wagner Theorem

Tags: statistical-mechanics, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking, spin-models, critical-phenomena

There are many presentations of the proof of the [Mermin-Wagner theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mermin%E2%80%93Wagner_theorem) in many different contexts (which talk about quantum vs. classical, existence of unique Gibbs measure or non-zero mean magnetization, talk about a Lie group of symmetries or just the XY model). I am aware of the relations between the various statements of the theorem (correlation inequalities e.g.) but:

I am looking for the simplest, most immediate and direct proof one could find for the following statement, which I guess is slightly stronger than the statement about mean magnetization:

*Theorem*: If $S:\{1,\dots,L\}^2\to\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$ is spin field of the $O(N)$ model ($N\geq2$), whose partition function is defined as $$ Z_L = \prod_{x\in\{1,\dots,L\}^2}\int_{S_x\in\mathbb{S}^{N-1}}\mathrm{d}\mu(S_x)\exp(\beta\sum_{x,y\in\{1,\dots,L\}^2:x\sim y}S_x\cdot S_y) $$ where $\mu$ is the uniform volume measure on $\mathbb{S}^{N-1}$ then $$ \lim_{x\to\infty}\lim_{L\to\infty}\mathbb{E}_L[S_x\cdot S_0] = 0\qquad(\beta > 0)\,. $$

The best is if you could prove (or sketch a proof) in a paragraph or few right here, otherwise if there is a great reference for this it would also be appreciated. Just as an example, googling the term, the first result is [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Mermin-Wagner_Theorem) and I think one has to work a bit to get from what they state to the statement above. It would be nice to have something direct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to prove this statement (actually, it gives you more, namely an upper bound on the 2-point function that decays with a power law) is the [argument by McBryan and Spencer](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01609854).

You can actually prove much more, namely the full rotation invariance of the limiting Gibbs state. In my opinion, the simplest proofs are due to [Dobrushin and Shlosman](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01609432) and [Pfister](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01942060). (They are actually applicable to much more general systems.)

Both proofs are explained pedagogically and in detail in Chapter 9 of [this book](http://www.unige.ch/math/folks/velenik/smbook), with some improvements. The McBryan-Spencer proof is given in Section 9.4.2, while (a variant of) Pfister's proof is given in Section 9.2.2.

Comment: Thanks! I somehow neglected McBryan-Spencer in this regard because I didn’t associate that proof with the usual Mermin-Wagner intuition. Oops!